# How to test for iOS devices I will never have access to

Tags: ios, ipad, debugging, testing

I recently released an app. It passed well through its testing phase with ten or so users running it day to day on a variety of devices. The app is not really intended for iPad but it works. 
On release day a small number of users pitched up saying that the app crashed or that the layout on their iPad was weird. All the complainants were using iPhone 5 or better or recent iPads. I have a pretty new iPhone5, and I went out and bought a new iPad mini. Everything tests perfectly.

So here is my question(s):
What is the strategy for debugging a bug I can't see and I can't test, and when I have no error to work from?
Are there known bugs in these newer devices that I need to be looking at?

Comment: Can you give me iTunes link of the app, to check it. As I have multiple devices. If it is free :P

Comment: A kind offer, but the app is unfortunately not free. I do appreciate the thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask users that are experiencing the issue and giving you feedback for sending you **screenshots**. This would help you to narrow issues with *weird* layout.

Add a **crash reporting** SDK to your project like [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) or [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) to get the crash logs. Then, when you symbolicate them, you will get the detailed information about which line of your code is crashing the app.

Comment: another thing I would add to this is if you can find out which iOS version the users are running it might help.

Comment: crashlytics reports which iOS version they are using.

Comment: I use test flight but not in production.